# PHP DOM-Document and XPath:fetch class data

Tags: python, php, xml

I've been having an issue trying to parse text in a span cass with DOM. Here is my code example. try to extract some lines out of a webpage - with following technique: with the Extraction of values of attributes of elements with DOMDocument

Here is what i have gathered and learned:

```
$remote = "http://website.com/";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($remote);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$node = $xpath->query('//span[@class="user"]');
echo $node;
```

and this returns the following error -> "Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string". I am so lost..

What I am trying to do is parse the user name between this tag;

```
<div class="widget plugin-meta">
            <h3 class="screen-reader-text">Meta</h3>
```

see more below:

Here the concrete example
view-source:https://wordpress.org/plugins/participants-database/
and https://wordpress.org/plugins/participants-database/

```
**goal:** i need the following data:
```

Version:
Last updated:
Active installations:
Tested up:

view-source:https://wordpress.org/plugins/participants-database/

**Proceedings;** i checked the source of the webpage. i tried to find out whether the texte is related to some kind of pattern.i have looked closely and found that all of them have class=”widget plugin-meta”.
Well - This will make extracting them, a piece of cake. I tried with the code below helps to filter html elements based on values of attributes.

but unfortunatly this ends up in a bad result; i need a helping hand and need to know how  to parse the above mentioned data

**goal:** i need the following data:
Version:
Last updated:
Active installations:
Tested up:

Comment: FYI never suppress errors with `@`, why blind yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Xpath expression can return a list of nodes or scalar values - depending on the expression. However `DOMXpath::query()` (and `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`) support node lists return values, only. For scalar results you need to use `DOMXpath::evaluate()`. Xpath allows has a function `string()` that cast the first found node into a string.

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<div class="widget plugin-meta">
  <h3 class="screen-reader-text">Meta</h3>
</div>
HTML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
@$document->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
echo $xpath->evaluate('string(//h3[@class="screen-reader-text"])');
```

If you expect multiple nodes, you will need to iterate them and get their text content.

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//h3[@class="screen-reader-text"]') as $h3) {
  echo $h3->textContent;   
}
```

Matching class attributes is a little more complex if you want to avoid partial matches (for example `plugin` as part of `plugin-meta`). They are a list of token separated by whitespaces. Xpath 1.0 has no function to directly match this. But it has methods that concatenate and to normalize strings.

```
$expression = '//div[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " plugin-meta ")]/h3';
foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $h3) {
  echo $h3->textContent;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `DOMNodeList` is an array with zero or more `DOMNode's`, and you can loop through them easily enough:

```
foreach ($nodeList as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php